# linux xpath encoding issue

Tags: bash, xpath, encoding

I am trying to use xpath to parse some xml in a bash script, but the encoding doesn't seem to behave. When I try:

```
echo '<car>mÿ cár</car>' | xpath -q -e '//car/text()'
```

It prints:

```
m� c�r
```

Even if I specify the encoding in the string:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><car>mÿ cár</car>'
```

The result is the same.
I'm not sure which xpath I'm using, it came with my Ubuntu. I opened on vi and it seems a simple bash script wrapper around the perl version. I found the exactly same code [here](https://github.com/UMiamiLibraries/RAMP/blob/master/utils/xpath), but I don't know the name or anything.

I'm willing to switch to another xpath implementation, as long as it is API compatible with this one, because there is a big code base being used that simple doesn't work with non-ascii chars (this is just a snippet of the problem). My terminal is UTF-8, and the actual data in the scripts is gotten via curl in UTF-8 as well.

I'm using xfce4-terminal 0.6.3, set to UTF-8 in the Preferences menu. My `LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: And your setting of LANG is?

Comment: `echo $LANG` prints `en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: how about using xmllint? i think it's a bit better, then few abstraction above libxml.

Comment: With `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` it looks okay: `mÿ cár`.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, @Cyrus, though I don't understand why. The problem is, this data is received from the server with the UTF-8 encoding set. But I guess I can try to replace this string with ISO-8859-1 or something... It bothers me that in the terminal, where I assumed I was typing in UTF-8, the string is being read as ISO...

Comment: xmllint seems to have the same problem even if I set the --encode switch

Comment: Please show the output of the `locale` command, in particular the **LC_ALL** variable.

Comment: I guess you can pipe through `iconv`.